# How to change the owner of a Google Calendar event to another organization's user using Java?

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

How do I change the owner of a Google Calendar event to another organization's user using Java?

I tried with the "https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/move" API with the below parameters

```
calendarId: "primary"
eventId: myEventId
destination: destination Email address
```

but the response shows a 404 Not Found error, as you can see below.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

When I attempt to change the owner using Google Calendar Web, it is successfully completed. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: by other organization do you mean a different organizational unit in the same workspace or a totally different workspace?

Comment: Not in the same workspace. I have to change the owner who is in different workspace.